# gdata API return no results

Tags: api, search, youtube, gdata, feed

I am just using this url to find the top rated videos on youtube with the word "scared".

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?q=scared

I am not using category or keywords because if I use it, Youtube doesn´t return videos without tags. 
I want that Youtube looking for "scared" by title and description, so I am using "search query term": "q=".

But, using "q=scared", this link returns only 1 video. Why?

Another example that are no result - using "most_recent" and keyword "scary":

/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_recent/-/%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com%2Fschemas%2F2007%2Fkeywords.cat%7Dscary

And using q="scary", no result neither:
/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_recent?q=scary

How can I get the videos using a "search" word?

Thanks!

Comment: What if there is only one top rated video that matches _scared_? Other words return more than one result.

Comment: Ok, let's forget the "top rated", I need to know the videos that using "scary" word. How can I find using search query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=scared

hopefully that will work.